# SuiteScript updating record using afterSubmit issues

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

What i'm trying to accomplish with a script is that when a user sets the sublist lines on a Sales order to create a dropship PO - On save,  NetSuite creates the PO and then script opens the PO, reads the vendorname field on the PO and assigns it to a custom record field on the Sales Order.

My issue is I can do this with beforeSubmit, but the user has to create the PO, then re-edit the Sales Order again and submit it for the script to be able to find the PO that was created.  I'm hoping to avoid this by using afterSubmit in which the PO should be assigned and linked at that point?

What I've come up with below doesn't error out, but its not updating the field.  I've tried adding a Commit Line after the setSublistValue but i then get an error about "Please Choose an Item to Add".  Any help would be appreciated.

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.1
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/record', 'N/runtime', 'N/search'], (record, runtime, search) => {
    function afterSubmit(context) {
        if (context.type === context.UserEventType.DELETE) return;
        log.debug('afterSubmit::context', context);
          var salesOrderId = context.newRecord.id;
          var salesOrderRecord = record.load({
                type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                id: salesOrderId,
                isDynamic: true
          });
        var dropshipId = salesOrderRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'links',
            fieldId: 'id',
            line: 0
        });
        if (dropshipId) {
            var purchaseOrderRecord = record.load({
                type: record.Type.PURCHASE_ORDER,
                id: dropshipId,
                isDynamic: true
            });
            const numLines = salesOrderRecord.getLineCount({
                sublistId: 'item'
            });
            for (let i = 0; i < numLines; i += 1) {
                var vendorCode = purchaseOrderRecord.getSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'vendorname',
                    line: i
                });
                salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'custcol_vencode',
                    value: vendorCode,
                    line: i
                });
            }
        salesOrderRecord.save();
        }
      
    }
    return {
        afterSubmit
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I needed to change it to selectLine, then setCurrentSublistValue, then commitLine.

```js
                salesOrderRecord.selectLine({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    line: i
                })
                salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'custcol_vencode',
                    value: vendorCode,
                    ignoreFieldChange: true
                });
                salesOrderRecord.commitLine({
                    sublistId: 'item'
                })
```